# Why may C# console applications call `Application.Run()`?

Tags: c#, windows

I have seen several examples of console applications calling `Application.Run()`, which starts a message loop on the current thread without a form.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900(v=vs.110).aspx

However, as the documentation states:

> In a Win32-based or Windows Forms application, a message loop is a
>   routine in code that processes user events, such as mouse clicks and
>   keyboard strokes.

So, it seems that `Application.Run()` only applies to GUI applications.

Then what is the purpose of calling `Application.Run()` from console applications, and is there a smarter way of achieving the same functionality in console applications?

Comment: why would you say that this only applies to GUI applications? it may very well be a console application because those can implement message loops just as well.

Comment: But, I've made lots of console applications without calling `Application.Run()`. The documentation says: "Every running Windows-based application requires an active message loop".

Comment: _"what is the purpose [...] and is there a smarter way?"_ - then show or link to those examples. There are myriad of reasons one could choose to do so, and as many alternatives, making this question too broad.

Comment: @CodeCaster - https://hinchley.net/articles/creating-a-key-logger-via-a-global-system-hook-using-powershell/

Comment: The fact that it makes good sense (most of the time) if you are building a GUI application does not mean it's a bad idea everywhere else.

Comment: your console application might even be listening for other external events or interrupts not even provided by a user. think of any active monitoring system that does not need a GUI like (for example) a headless hydroponics controller.

Comment: As for "why *may* a console application do that", instead first try to answer why it might *not*. if there's no good reason *not* to allow it, why impose an unnecessary restriction?

Comment: You need a message loop to use COM with an STA: Windows uses message loops for more than GUI functions.

Comment: *is there a smarter way of achieving the same functionality in console applications?* - too ambiguous and wishlist. Obviously `Application.Run` facilitates the console window. In my experience often you can do unsupported things, sure don't use `Application.Run` in your `Main()` but don't expect it to be supported. Out of curiosity how are you wiring up the Message loop without the `Application.Run`?

Comment: @TimothyGroote - does a console application runs a message loop even if I don’t call Application.Run()? If not, how is it processing keyboard events?

Comment: @Shuzheng in order for the console itself to work, it needs to implement a message loop. you get to decide whether or not your console application hooks into that, or implements its own, or does neither.

Answer (score 8):

You have to see the bigger picture, it is not Application.Run() that creates a GUI app.  It is creating a window that does.  The class libraries that support a window, as well as the many system and 3rd party components that interact with it, are never thread-safe.  But a GUI must always deal with notifications generated from different threads, typically located in different processes or the OS.

Tricky problem, but it is one that is very common in software engineering and has a universal solution, you must solve the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  Which requires a thread-safe queue, it is provided by the OS.  And a loop that empties that queue and dispatches the notifications, that is what Application.Run() does.

Also the only practical way to get code to run on a *specific* thread.  Which seems like something that should be easy to do, but is not.  A thread is always busy executing code, you can't just arbitrarily interrupt it and force it to do something else, that creates horrible re-entrancy problems.  The dispatcher loop is the safe spot at which a thread signals that it is idle and ready to do something else.  Probably why you saw it used in a console mode app.  Especially a dead-ringer when you see async/await in that code.